# How to detect malformed UTF characters

Tags: perl, utf-8, character-encoding

I want to detect and replace malformed UTF-8 characters with blank space using a Perl script while loading the data using SQL*Loader. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Consider Python. It allows to extend codecs with user-defined error handlers, so you can replace undecodable bytes with anything you want.

```
import codecs
codecs.register_error('spacer', lambda ex: (u' ', ex.start + 1))
s = 'spam\xb0\xc0eggs\xd0bacon'.decode('utf8', 'spacer')
print s.encode('utf8')
```

This prints:

```
spam  eggs bacon
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: (Removed bit about SQL Loader as it seems to no longer be relevant.)

One problem is going to be working out what counts as the "end" of a malformed UTF-8 character. It's easy to say what's illegal, but it may not be obvious where the next legal character starts.

Comment: Finding where the next character starts is easy - that's one of the very cool things about UTF-8's design.  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629

Comment: Easy only in well-formed UTF-8. Imagine a duplicate lead-byte being inserted - you would have to skip the first occurrance. If you simply followed the UTF-8 rules, the next character would seem to start with the last byte of the character whose lead byte was duplicated.

Comment: @MSalters: That's the kind of thing I was thinking about, but I wasn't sure enough of myself :)

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629) describes the structure of UTF-8 characters.  If you take a look at that, you'll see that it's pretty straightforward to find invalid characters, AND that the next character boundary is always easy to find (it's a character < 128, or one of the "long character" start markers, with leading bits of 110, 1110, or 11110).

But BKB is probably correct - the easiest answer is to let perl do it for you, although I'm not sure what Perl does when it detects the incorrect utf-8 with that filter in effect.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, instead of the usual output,  I got a cron message saying:

```
/etc/cron.daily/syslogrotate:
Malformed UTF-8 character (fatal) at /root/bin/maillogstats.pl line 55, <> line 12335.
```

The log file contained a line rendered in less -N like so:

```
 12335 Apr 29 14:07:46 22 north courieresmtpd: error,relay=***.***.125.226,port=41522,msg="502 ESMTP command error",cmd: ....<A7>.
```

The script started with these statements:

```
use utf8;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
```

I changed it according to a suggestion found in [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Perl_Programming/Unicode_UTF-8&oldid=4007996#Input_-_STDIN)

```
use utf8;
use open qw(:std :encoding(UTF-8));
```

And that's it.